# I am trying to create a separate HTTPServer alongside the one running for management and metrics exposure. Is it a good idea?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, prometheus, micrometer

I am running a spring boot application, and I have added Micrometer for exposing the metrics for Prometheus to scrape. My requirement is that the prometheus URL should not be beneath /actuator and neither it should be anything like `/prometheus`. It should be accessible by hitting `/` on a different port other than the port specified for management using `management.server.port`. So I thought of creating a `com.sun.net.httpserver` type HTTP server on a separate thread which will listen on my desired port and respond to requests made to `/` with the metrics. This is feasible, however I am wondering if this would be a good idea in terms of:

1. Scalability.
2. Accuracy in reading the system metrics and exposing.
3. What if the thread gets interrupted at any point and therefore stop!

Do spring's management APIs like `healthcheck`,`heartbeat`,`prometheus` (`prometheus` when micrometer is added) run on different instance of Tomcat?

Comment: The whole point of the management server (or actual connector) is that it runs on a different port from the actual application. Why would you need another for allowing Prometheus access to your endpoint? If you really want you will need to add a separate connector to the tomcat instance you are using.

Comment: *My requirement is that the prometheus URL should not be beneath /actuator* please explain the reasoning for your requirement.

Comment: I will need another port for Prometheus for the reason that things like `healthcheck` and few other actuator data are required on a specific port and the prometheus end point is required on a different port altogether. Now if I override `management.server.port` to say 2121, then everything for management will be read from this port which is not desired. And not only this, one should be able to hit `/` to get all the metrics exposed by micrometer, anything like `/actuator/prometheus' or `/prometheus` is undesirable.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- the reasoning is that it is a business requirement, not my decision.